# converting client side validation to server side from .net core 2.0 to 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to convert below LINQ query from the client-side to the server-side. Since .net core 3.1 no longer supports client-side validations

```
    var response = await _db.MyTable
    .Where(ba =>
    ba.status == null
    && (today - (ba.Reminder ?? ba.CreatedOn)).TotalDays > 6
    && (today < ba.CreatedOn.AddDays(50) && ba.AccountNumber == null ||
    futureAccounts.Contains(ba.AccountNumber)))
    .Include(ba => ba.AccountInfo)
    .Where(ba => ba.AccountInfo.Any(x => x.Type.Equals("EC")))
    .Include(b => b.Branch)
.Include(ba => ba.Services).ThenInclude(s => s.Name)
.OrderBy(ba => ba.CreatedOn)
.Skip(skip)
.Take(500)
.ToListAsync();
```

I tried all my options it still says:

> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There's been a breaking change in EF3 .Starting with 3.0, EF Core only allows expressions in the top-level projection (the last Select() call in the query) to be evaluated on the client. When expressions in any other part of the query can't be converted to either SQL or a parameter, an exception is thrown.

To evaluate a predicate condition on the client, try to use below code with `AsEnumerable()`

```
var response  =    _db.MyTable
                        .Include(ba => ba.AccountInfo)
                        .Include(b => b.Branch)
                        .Include(ba => ba.Services).ThenInclude(s => s.Name)
                        .AsEnumerable()// switches to LINQ to Objects
                        .Where(ba =>
                            ba.status == null
                            && (today - (ba.Reminder ?? ba.CreatedOn)).TotalDays > 6
                            && (today < ba.CreatedOn.AddDays(50) && ba.AccountNumber == null ||
                            futureAccounts.Contains(ba.AccountNumber)))

                        .Where(ba => ba.AccountInfo.Any(x => x.Type.Equals("EC")))

                        .OrderBy(ba => ba.CreatedOn)
                        .Skip(skip)
                        .Take(500)
                        .ToList();
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#restricted-client-evaluation

Comment: I have seen the entity framework has some issues with AsEnumerable instead I was trying to rewrite using AsQuerable().. I think I figured it out. Thank you Xing!!